# How to make a specific texture that load in the game as Cloth and make it look like leather

Tags: texturing, texture-baking

I ve extracted some textures of an outfit from a video game to be precise ( Assassin's Creed : Unity ) along with some meshes What i wanna do is edit the Textures that appear as cloth and make them look like leather so i can have this leather coat on the outfit but idk how to do it since i have no experience at all with textures.I ve looked around for quite a while and an outside party told me that it’ll mostly be dictated by the normal/specular maps I believe. The textures I extracted are the following : Diffusemap, Normalmap, Mask1map. I included a picture of the alpha channel of the normal map if that helps give a clear picture.[image] [image][image][image]

Comment: So I guess you need to do it in an image editor software and change the color of the Diffuse to brown tint, and also light (or darken) the image used for Specular (or si it Roughness). You can also do it directly in the Shader Editor if you are familiar with the Color nodes

Comment: it worked i got the results i expected thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

So I guess you need to do it in an image editor software and change the color of the *Diffuse* image to a brown tint, and also light (or darken) the image used for *Specular* (or maybe it is for *Roughness*?). You can also do it directly in the *Shader Editor* if you are familiar with the *Color* nodes, example put a *Hue Saturation Value* node after the *Image Texture* and tweak the parameters.